# Как узнать, является ли Type наследником другого Type?

Tags: c#

Предположим есть классы

`class Window1 : Window`

и

`class Window2 : Window1`

Если я имею экземпляр класса Window2, то я легко могу определить, что он наследник Window так

```
if (theWindow2 is Window) { }
```

А как быть, если у меня не экземпляр класса, а тип?

Первое, что пришло на ум - `TheType.BaseType`. Но в этом случае мне придется рекурсивно получать базовый класс, пока не достигну нужного, либо пока базовый тип не будет равен null. Может, есть более быстрый способ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Type.IsSubclassOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx)?

```
typeof(Window2).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Window1))
```

Comment: А в моем случае тоже сработает? То есть `typeof(Window2).IsSubclassOf(typeof(Window))`, где Window2 не прямой наследник Window

Comment: @iRumba сработает

Comment: Маленькое дополнение: если вы хотите, чтобы работало и для интерфейсов, используйте [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/03/type-issubclssof-and-type-isassignablefrom/).

Answer (score 4):

Используйте метод IsSubclassOf класса Type
Например:

```
Type second = typeof(SecondChild);
Type first = typeof(FirstChild);
bool flag = second.IsSubclassOf(first);
```